# Trying to merge two videos from my photo roll with Flutter ffmpeg without success

Tags: flutter, video, ffmpeg, merge

My goal is to merge too video I pick from my photo roll.
My code starts as follows:

```dart
// videos[0] contains: "content://media/external/video/media/2779"
 final v1 = await videos[0].getMediaUrl();
    if (v1 == null) return;
    final v1Path = await LecleFlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(uri: v1);
```

But printing `v1Path`give a path with `jpeg` extension:
`/data/user/0/com.example.shokaze/cache/OutputFile_1669939088711.jpeg' which I though would have bear` mp4` as it is a video.

Why is it so?

Another question I have is how can I make a relevant path so that the ffmpeg video appears in my roll after its creation? Should I do the following and provide `outputPath`to the code?

The command it executes is:
`-i /data/user/0/com.example.shokaze/cache/OutputFile_1669940421875.jpeg -i /data/user/0/com.example.shokaze/cache/OutputFile_1669940428723.jpeg -filter_complex '[0:0][1:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[out]' -map '[out]' /data/user/0/com.example.shokaze/app_flutter/output.mp4`

And I get an error:
`I/flutter (30190): error 1`

My code is as follows:

```dart
    String output = "content://media/external/video/media/output";
    final outputPath = await LecleFlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(uri: output);
    if (outputPath == null) return;
```

The full code is as follows:

```dart
// Makes the final video by merging all videos from the mixing table
  void makeFinalVideo() async {
    if (videos.length < 2) return;

    final v1 = await videos[0].getMediaUrl();
    if (v1 == null) return;
    final v1Path = await LecleFlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(uri: v1);
    if (v1Path == null) return;
    //String v1 = "";
    final v2 = await videos[1].getMediaUrl();
    if (v2 == null) return;
    final v2Path = await LecleFlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(uri: v2);
    if (v2Path == null) return;
    String output = "content://media/external/video/media/output";
    final outputPath = "";
    // await LecleFlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(uri: output);
    // if (outputPath == null) return;

    Video.merge(v1Path, v2Path, outputPath);
  }



class Video {
  /// Merges the video [v1] with [v2] as [output] video located in app doc path
  static void merge(String v1, String v2, String output) async {
    final appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    //final appDir = await syspaths.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String rawDocumentPath = appDocDir.path;
    final outputPath = '$rawDocumentPath/output.mp4';

    final command =
        '-i $v1 -i $v2 -filter_complex \'[0:0][1:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[out]\' -map \'[out]\' $outputPath';
    //await execute(command);
    try {
      final r = await FFmpegKit.execute(command);

      //.then((rc) => print("FFmpeg process exited with rc $rc"));
      print("Result: $r");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Exception: $e");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
String commandToExecute = '-y -i ${_storedVideoOne!.path} -i ${_storedVideoTwo!.path} -r 24000/1001 -filter_complex \'[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[out]\' -map \'[out]\' $outputPath';
```